# How to fade out an SVG (bottom opacity 0, top opacity 1) using linear gradient mask?

Tags: svg, linear-gradients

I have an SVG like this:

```
<svg width="1848" height="862" viewBox="0 0 1848 862" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clip0_529_2072">
      <rect width="1848" height="862" fill="white" />
    </clipPath>
    <linearGradient id="fadeGrad" x2="0%" y2="100%">
      <stop offset="0.5" stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0" />
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="white" stop-opacity="1" />
    </linearGradient>
    <mask id="fade" maskContentUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <rect width="1848" height="862" fill="url(#fadeGrad)" />
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <g clip-path="url(#clip0_529_2072)" mask="url(#fade)">
    <g opacity="0.15">
      <rect x="407.504" y="361.524" width="23.9244" height="23.9244" rx="1.32913" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <path d="M487.43 363.518C487.942 362.632 489.221 362.632 489.732 363.518L501.243 383.455C501.754 384.341 501.115 385.449 500.092 385.449H477.07C476.047 385.449 475.408 384.341 475.919 383.455L487.43 363.518Z" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <rect opacity="0.72" x="112.436" y="25.2535" width="28.47" height="28.47" rx="1.32913" transform="rotate(-14 112.436 25.2535)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <path opacity="0.92" d="M199.829 48.6394C200.848 48.7285 201.389 49.8877 200.802 50.7258L186.33 71.3941C185.743 72.2322 184.469 72.1207 184.036 71.1934L173.373 48.3261C172.941 47.3988 173.674 46.3511 174.694 46.4403L199.829 48.6394Z" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <circle opacity="0.89" cx="331.549" cy="32.5986" r="10.0483" transform="rotate(18 331.549 32.5986)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <rect opacity="0.72" x="384.909" y="43.8614" width="15.7901" height="15.7901" rx="1.32913" transform="rotate(47 384.909 43.8614)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <path opacity="0.99" d="M502.651 46.1519C503.672 46.2233 504.232 47.3728 503.66 48.2211L493.568 63.1841C492.995 64.0324 491.72 63.9431 491.271 63.0235L483.359 46.8015C482.91 45.8819 483.626 44.8216 484.646 44.8929L502.651 46.1519Z" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <circle opacity="0.86" cx="641.604" cy="27.6894" r="11.4837" transform="rotate(-11 641.604 27.6894)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <path opacity="0.93" d="M707.963 26.7505C708.228 25.7622 709.463 25.4312 710.187 26.1546L722.949 38.917C723.673 39.6405 723.342 40.8759 722.353 41.1407L704.92 45.812C703.931 46.0768 703.027 45.1725 703.292 44.1842L707.963 26.7505Z" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <rect opacity="0.94" x="741.117" y="6.64569" width="21.0535" height="21.0535" rx="1.32913" transform="rotate(-122 741.117 6.64569)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <path opacity="0.9" d="M883.534 49.3855C884.557 49.3677 885.216 50.4639 884.72 51.3588L876.371 66.4197C875.875 67.3146 874.597 67.3369 874.07 66.4599L865.201 51.6995C864.674 50.8225 865.294 49.7039 866.317 49.686L883.534 49.3855Z" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <circle opacity="0.93" cx="1007.81" cy="17.8048" r="13.8762" transform="rotate(-76 1007.81 17.8048)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <rect opacity="0.98" x="1042.83" y="27.9118" width="23.9244" height="23.9244" rx="1.32913" transform="rotate(162 1042.83 27.9118)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <circle cx="1185.31" cy="17.5446" r="14.3546" transform="rotate(-180 1185.31 17.5446)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <circle opacity="0.87" cx="1254.92" cy="12.65" r="9.56976" transform="rotate(-65 1254.92 12.65)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <circle opacity="0.71" cx="1392.7" cy="41.544" r="9.68939" transform="rotate(-38 1392.7 41.544)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <path opacity="0.88" d="M1467.05 47.0341C1468.06 46.8389 1468.9 47.8041 1468.56 48.7715L1461.07 70.5386C1460.74 71.506 1459.48 71.75 1458.81 70.9778L1443.71 53.6035C1443.03 52.8313 1443.45 51.622 1444.45 51.4267L1467.05 47.0341Z" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <path opacity="0.89" d="M1548.09 -5.22846C1547.07 -5.35316 1546.57 -6.53045 1547.19 -7.34758L1564.2 -29.9251C1564.82 -30.7422 1566.09 -30.5864 1566.49 -29.6445L1577.53 -3.62176C1577.93 -2.67993 1577.16 -1.65851 1576.15 -1.7832L1548.09 -5.22846Z" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <rect opacity="0.71" x="1724.68" y="6.64569" width="26.7953" height="26.7953" rx="1.32913" transform="rotate(-45 1724.68 6.64569)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <path opacity="0.7" d="M1768.7 30.1902C1769.61 29.7257 1770.69 30.4222 1770.63 31.444L1769.34 56.089C1769.29 57.1108 1768.15 57.6914 1767.29 57.1341L1746.59 43.6931C1745.73 43.1358 1745.8 41.8586 1746.71 41.3941L1768.7 30.1902Z" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <path opacity="0.95" d="M48.2634 74.7334C47.4252 75.3203 46.2661 74.7798 46.1769 73.7605L44.652 56.3309C44.5629 55.3116 45.6105 54.5781 46.5378 55.0105L62.3947 62.4047C63.322 62.8371 63.4335 64.1112 62.5954 64.698L48.2634 74.7334Z" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <rect opacity="0.7" x="172.247" y="58.8511" width="21.532" height="21.532" rx="1.32913" transform="rotate(-51 172.247 58.8511)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <circle opacity="0.7" cx="294.255" cy="70.8699" r="9.92863" transform="rotate(-67 294.255 70.8699)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <rect opacity="0.81" x="400.858" y="78.7881" width="14.3546" height="14.3546" rx="1.32913" transform="rotate(-26 400.858 78.7881)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <path opacity="0.72" d="M534.287 78.4336C534.022 77.4453 534.927 76.541 535.915 76.8058L550.147 80.6191C551.135 80.884 551.466 82.1193 550.743 82.8428L540.324 93.2611C539.601 93.9846 538.365 93.6535 538.101 92.6652L534.287 78.4336Z" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <path opacity="0.93" d="M592.734 47.7218C591.721 47.8642 590.933 46.8564 591.317 45.9077L598.492 28.1487C598.875 27.2001 600.142 27.0221 600.772 27.8283L612.564 42.9217C613.194 43.7279 612.715 44.9138 611.701 45.0562L592.734 47.7218Z" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <rect opacity="0.8" x="649.406" y="49.5471" width="22.0105" height="22.0105" rx="1.32913" transform="rotate(-83 649.406 49.5471)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <path opacity="0.79" d="M782.91 71.9042C783.21 70.9257 784.456 70.638 785.153 71.3863L794.825 81.7577C795.523 82.506 795.149 83.7291 794.152 83.9593L780.334 87.1493C779.337 87.3795 778.465 86.4441 778.764 85.4657L782.91 71.9042Z" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <path opacity="0.87" d="M875.592 71.8921C875.327 72.8804 874.092 73.2114 873.369 72.4879L860.997 60.1162C860.273 59.3927 860.604 58.1574 861.593 57.8925L878.493 53.3642C879.481 53.0994 880.385 54.0038 880.121 54.9921L875.592 71.8921Z" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <rect opacity="0.88" x="998.969" y="65.4968" width="21.0535" height="21.0535" rx="1.32913" transform="rotate(87 998.969 65.4968)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <path opacity="0.94" d="M1140.67 47.3072C1141.1 46.3799 1142.38 46.2684 1142.97 47.1065L1159.34 70.4903C1159.93 71.3285 1159.38 72.4876 1158.37 72.5768L1129.93 75.0648C1128.91 75.1539 1128.18 74.1063 1128.61 73.179L1140.67 47.3072Z" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <circle opacity="0.92" cx="1208.02" cy="71.1757" r="12.9192" transform="rotate(-138 1208.02 71.1757)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <rect opacity="0.78" x="1315.3" y="85.4338" width="24.8814" height="24.8814" rx="1.32913" transform="rotate(81 1315.3 85.4338)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <path opacity="0.9" d="M1430.16 55.2327C1429.17 54.9679 1428.84 53.7325 1429.56 53.009L1446.81 35.7538C1447.54 35.0303 1448.77 35.3613 1449.04 36.3496L1455.35 59.9207C1455.62 60.909 1454.71 61.8133 1453.73 61.5485L1430.16 55.2327Z" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <circle opacity="0.72" cx="1519.59" cy="77.6056" r="8.37354" transform="rotate(100 1519.59 77.6056)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <rect opacity="0.86" x="1595.75" y="54.8637" width="20.575" height="20.575" rx="1.32913" transform="rotate(164 1595.75 54.8637)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <path opacity="0.72" d="M1646.46 56.4546C1646.15 57.4277 1644.89 57.6936 1644.21 56.9332L1626.22 36.9509C1625.53 36.1906 1625.93 34.9742 1626.93 34.7615L1653.23 29.171C1654.23 28.9582 1655.09 29.9087 1654.77 30.8818L1646.46 56.4546Z" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <path opacity="0.87" d="M1756.22 59.9023C1755.85 60.8575 1754.59 61.0576 1753.94 60.2624L1743.8 47.7388C1743.16 46.9436 1743.62 45.7496 1744.63 45.5896L1760.54 43.0686C1761.55 42.9086 1762.36 43.9025 1761.99 44.8577L1756.22 59.9023Z" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <circle opacity="0.72" cx="96.8289" cy="116.07" r="12.3211" transform="rotate(93 96.8289 116.07)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <circle opacity="0.83" cx="194.679" cy="84.4305" r="9.80901" transform="rotate(-119 194.679 84.4305)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <path opacity="0.92" d="M284.317 124.301C283.984 125.269 282.729 125.513 282.058 124.741L272.392 113.621C271.72 112.849 272.137 111.64 273.141 111.444L287.604 108.633C288.608 108.438 289.447 109.403 289.114 110.371L284.317 124.301Z" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <rect opacity="0.81" x="364.972" y="116.373" width="24.1637" height="24.1637" rx="1.32913" transform="rotate(101 364.972 116.373)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <rect opacity="0.99" x="444.72" y="103.082" width="26.7953" height="26.7953" rx="1.32913" transform="rotate(19 444.72 103.082)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <circle opacity="0.9" cx="634.485" cy="132.988" r="10.6464" transform="rotate(-27 634.485 132.988)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <circle opacity="0.9" cx="693.638" cy="127.327" r="7.77543" transform="rotate(50 693.638 127.327)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <rect opacity="0.9" x="774.345" y="108.398" width="23.6852" height="23.6852" rx="1.32913" transform="rotate(-163 774.345 108.398)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <circle opacity="0.99" cx="924.989" cy="126.554" r="8.85203" transform="rotate(90 924.989 126.554)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <rect opacity="0.93" x="1018.91" y="96.436" width="27.7523" height="27.7523" rx="1.32913" transform="rotate(-173 1018.91 96.436)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <circle opacity="0.99" cx="1047.67" cy="121.531" r="11.6033" transform="rotate(-146 1047.67 121.531)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <circle opacity="0.89" cx="1198.24" cy="111.947" r="14.235" transform="rotate(178 1198.24 111.947)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <circle opacity="0.87" cx="1290.39" cy="108.095" r="12.3211" transform="rotate(93 1290.39 108.095)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <path opacity="0.7" d="M1368.54 112.789C1367.85 112.029 1368.25 110.813 1369.25 110.6L1393.12 105.526C1394.12 105.314 1394.97 106.264 1394.66 107.237L1387.12 130.445C1386.8 131.419 1385.55 131.684 1384.87 130.924L1368.54 112.789Z" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <rect opacity="0.88" x="1441.57" y="99.0943" width="23.6852" height="23.6852" rx="1.32913" transform="rotate(112 1441.57 99.0943)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <rect opacity="0.99" x="1601.07" y="97.7652" width="20.3357" height="20.3357" rx="1.32913" transform="rotate(168 1601.07 97.7652)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <rect opacity="0.98" x="1644.93" y="115.044" width="20.0965" height="20.0965" rx="1.32913" transform="rotate(65 1644.93 115.044)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <path opacity="0.83" d="M1733.45 88.7933C1732.43 88.8825 1731.7 87.8348 1732.13 86.9075L1743.96 61.5364C1744.4 60.6091 1745.67 60.4977 1746.26 61.3358L1762.31 84.267C1762.9 85.1052 1762.36 86.2643 1761.34 86.3535L1733.45 88.7933Z" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <circle opacity="0.79" cx="89.2603" cy="153.483" r="9.92863" transform="rotate(172 89.2603 153.483)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <circle opacity="0.93" cx="210.555" cy="165.098" r="9.45014" transform="rotate(-166 210.555 165.098)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <path opacity="0.87" d="M291.409 135.948C290.435 135.632 290.17 134.381 290.93 133.696L312.144 114.595C312.904 113.91 314.121 114.306 314.333 115.306L320.269 143.229C320.481 144.23 319.531 145.086 318.558 144.769L291.409 135.948Z" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <rect opacity="0.91" x="387.567" y="167.249" width="25.3599" height="25.3599" rx="1.32913" transform="rotate(-176 387.567 167.249)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <path opacity="0.76" d="M518.978 149.258C519.138 150.268 518.144 151.073 517.189 150.706L496.986 142.951C496.031 142.585 495.831 141.321 496.626 140.677L513.443 127.059C514.238 126.415 515.432 126.873 515.593 127.884L518.978 149.258Z" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <rect opacity="0.77" x="584.279" y="171.237" width="27.9916" height="27.9916" rx="1.32913" transform="rotate(114 584.279 171.237)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <path d="M684.904 166.948C684.143 166.263 684.409 165.012 685.382 164.696L706.489 157.838C707.462 157.522 708.412 158.378 708.2 159.379L703.586 181.086C703.373 182.087 702.156 182.482 701.396 181.798L684.904 166.948Z" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <path opacity="0.99" d="M753.68 179.413C754.677 179.643 755.051 180.866 754.353 181.615L735.261 202.088C734.563 202.836 733.317 202.549 733.018 201.57L724.834 174.8C724.534 173.821 725.407 172.886 726.404 173.116L753.68 179.413Z" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <circle opacity="0.76" cx="884.87" cy="173.423" r="8.37354" transform="rotate(31 884.87 173.423)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <path opacity="0.9" d="M968.451 176.592C968.273 177.6 967.071 178.037 966.287 177.379L950.557 164.18C949.773 163.522 949.995 162.263 950.956 161.913L970.253 154.889C971.214 154.539 972.194 155.361 972.016 156.369L968.451 176.592Z" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <rect opacity="0.83" x="1099.98" y="181.87" width="16.5078" height="16.5078" rx="1.32913" transform="rotate(-137 1099.98 181.87)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <rect opacity="0.92" x="1227.58" y="179.212" width="21.0535" height="21.0535" rx="1.32913" transform="rotate(-74 1227.58 179.212)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <rect opacity="0.91" x="1292.71" y="161.933" width="14.5939" height="14.5939" rx="1.32913" transform="rotate(167 1292.71 161.933)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <path opacity="0.75" d="M1414.12 170.366C1414.79 169.594 1416.05 169.838 1416.38 170.805L1422.89 189.699C1423.22 190.667 1422.38 191.632 1421.38 191.437L1401.76 187.624C1400.76 187.429 1400.34 186.219 1401.01 185.447L1414.12 170.366Z" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <rect opacity="0.97" x="1484.1" y="160.604" width="28.47" height="28.47" rx="1.32913" transform="rotate(125 1484.1 160.604)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <circle opacity="0.71" cx="1573.97" cy="167.125" r="13.1584" transform="rotate(152 1573.97 167.125)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <rect opacity="0.75" x="1639.61" y="181.87" width="27.2738" height="27.2738" rx="1.32913" transform="rotate(144 1639.61 181.87)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <circle opacity="0.77" cx="1834.01" cy="180.473" r="8.49317" transform="rotate(37 1834.01 180.473)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <circle opacity="0.78" cx="51.0069" cy="233.076" r="7.29694" transform="rotate(24 51.0069 233.076)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <circle opacity="0.86" cx="128.593" cy="197.128" r="12.4407" transform="rotate(121 128.593 197.128)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <path opacity="0.91" d="M254.16 198.319C254.373 197.319 255.589 196.923 256.35 197.608L267.299 207.467C268.059 208.151 267.793 209.402 266.82 209.719L252.808 214.272C251.835 214.588 250.884 213.732 251.097 212.731L254.16 198.319Z" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <circle opacity="0.91" cx="438.537" cy="200.245" r="10.5267" transform="rotate(-94 438.537 200.245)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <rect opacity="0.98" x="452.695" y="219.455" width="19.1395" height="19.1395" rx="1.32913" transform="rotate(107 452.695 219.455)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <rect opacity="0.95" x="633.457" y="190.214" width="24.4029" height="24.4029" rx="1.32913" transform="rotate(-120 633.457 190.214)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <circle opacity="0.93" cx="670.395" cy="222.284" r="8.97165" transform="rotate(28 670.395 222.284)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <circle opacity="0.86" cx="784.916" cy="208.493" r="14.3546" transform="rotate(30 784.916 208.493)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <rect opacity="0.8" x="924.537" y="207.493" width="21.532" height="21.532" rx="1.32913" transform="rotate(119 924.537 207.493)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <path opacity="0.72" d="M925.872 205.784C925.215 206.568 923.955 206.346 923.605 205.384L916.298 185.309C915.948 184.347 916.771 183.368 917.778 183.545L938.817 187.255C939.825 187.433 940.262 188.634 939.605 189.418L925.872 205.784Z" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <rect opacity="0.75" x="1058.78" y="218.126" width="24.1637" height="24.1637" rx="1.32913" transform="rotate(-35 1058.78 218.126)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <circle cx="1153.61" cy="232.03" r="10.5267" transform="rotate(117 1153.61 232.03)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <circle opacity="0.74" cx="1304.88" cy="203.461" r="10.6464" transform="rotate(-35 1304.88 203.461)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <rect opacity="0.86" x="1345.87" y="212.809" width="18.9003" height="18.9003" rx="1.32913" transform="rotate(-51 1345.87 212.809)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <rect opacity="0.82" x="1438.91" y="220.784" width="19.1395" height="19.1395" rx="1.32913" transform="rotate(107 1438.91 220.784)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <circle opacity="0.86" cx="1551.56" cy="221.788" r="11.2445" transform="rotate(-71 1551.56 221.788)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <path opacity="0.72" d="M1689.75 194.459C1689.09 195.242 1687.83 195.02 1687.48 194.059L1682.35 179.954C1682 178.993 1682.82 178.013 1683.83 178.191L1698.61 180.797C1699.62 180.975 1700.06 182.177 1699.4 182.96L1689.75 194.459Z" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <rect opacity="0.9" x="1747.27" y="215.467" width="18.9003" height="18.9003" rx="1.32913" transform="rotate(-149 1747.27 215.467)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <circle opacity="0.91" cx="58.043" cy="281.693" r="9.09128" transform="rotate(100 58.043 281.693)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <rect opacity="0.77" x="236.046" y="234.444" width="28.7093" height="28.7093" rx="1.32913" transform="rotate(131 236.046 234.444)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <rect opacity="0.93" x="303.831" y="257.04" width="20.0965" height="20.0965" rx="1.32913" transform="rotate(168 303.831 257.04)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <rect opacity="0.95" x="391.554" y="243.748" width="16.9863" height="16.9863" rx="1.32913" transform="rotate(-75 391.554 243.748)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <rect opacity="0.7" x="515.164" y="266.344" width="23.9244" height="23.9244" rx="1.32913" transform="rotate(-158 515.164 266.344)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <rect opacity="0.86" x="634.786" y="275.648" width="17.2256" height="17.2256" rx="1.32913" transform="rotate(34 634.786 275.648)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <rect opacity="0.96" x="717.192" y="271.66" width="24.8814" height="24.8814" rx="1.32913" transform="rotate(-9 717.192 271.66)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <path opacity="0.84" d="M735.951 266.589C735.809 267.602 734.623 268.081 733.816 267.451L713.716 251.747C712.91 251.118 713.088 249.851 714.037 249.468L737.687 239.912C738.635 239.529 739.643 240.317 739.501 241.33L735.951 266.589Z" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <rect x="928.524" y="239.761" width="16.9863" height="16.9863" rx="1.32913" transform="rotate(127 928.524 239.761)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <rect opacity="0.98" x="985.677" y="263.685" width="26.0776" height="26.0776" rx="1.32913" transform="rotate(44 985.677 263.685)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <circle opacity="0.78" cx="1077.39" cy="250.272" r="11.3641" transform="rotate(-135 1077.39 250.272)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <circle opacity="0.73" cx="1179.14" cy="277.508" r="12.0818" transform="rotate(9 1179.14 277.508)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <circle opacity="0.94" cx="1250.78" cy="255.621" r="13.0388" transform="rotate(83 1250.78 255.621)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <path opacity="0.86" d="M1390.44 250.199C1391.25 249.569 1392.43 250.048 1392.58 251.062L1394.32 263.463C1394.46 264.477 1393.45 265.264 1392.51 264.881L1380.89 260.189C1379.95 259.806 1379.77 258.539 1380.57 257.91L1390.44 250.199Z" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <rect opacity="0.95" x="1472.14" y="253.052" width="17.9433" height="17.9433" rx="1.32913" transform="rotate(65 1472.14 253.052)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <path opacity="0.94" d="M1565.08 273.54C1565.31 274.537 1564.37 275.409 1563.39 275.11L1541.64 268.46C1540.66 268.161 1540.37 266.915 1541.12 266.217L1557.76 250.705C1558.51 250.007 1559.73 250.381 1559.96 251.378L1565.08 273.54Z" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <rect opacity="0.75" x="1662.21" y="259.698" width="24.6421" height="24.6421" rx="1.32913" transform="rotate(-179 1662.21 259.698)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <circle opacity="0.74" cx="1754.06" cy="276.977" r="13.9958" transform="rotate(135 1754.06 276.977)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <path opacity="0.97" d="M150.643 309.39C150.59 308.368 151.662 307.672 152.574 308.136L169.64 316.832C170.552 317.296 170.619 318.574 169.76 319.131L153.697 329.563C152.839 330.12 151.699 329.539 151.646 328.518L150.643 309.39Z" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <path opacity="0.76" d="M144.539 318.751C143.701 319.338 142.542 318.798 142.453 317.779L141.024 301.45C140.935 300.431 141.983 299.697 142.91 300.129L157.765 307.057C158.693 307.489 158.804 308.763 157.966 309.35L144.539 318.751Z" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <circle opacity="0.81" cx="323.937" cy="276.144" r="12.9192" transform="rotate(-165 323.937 276.144)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <rect opacity="0.9" x="414.15" y="294.625" width="24.8814" height="24.8814" rx="1.32913" transform="rotate(69 414.15 294.625)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <circle opacity="0.79" cx="470.94" cy="275.159" r="8.25392" transform="rotate(-85 470.94 275.159)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <path opacity="0.81" d="M616.551 292.558C616.605 291.536 617.744 290.956 618.602 291.513L637.214 303.6C638.073 304.157 638.006 305.434 637.094 305.899L617.32 315.974C616.409 316.439 615.336 315.742 615.39 314.72L616.551 292.558Z" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <rect opacity="0.99" x="731.813" y="315.891" width="16.5078" height="16.5078" rx="1.32913" transform="rotate(-50 731.813 315.891)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <path opacity="0.73" d="M821.363 317.862C821.763 316.92 823.032 316.764 823.648 317.581L833.513 330.672C834.128 331.489 833.629 332.666 832.613 332.791L816.344 334.789C815.329 334.913 814.559 333.892 814.959 332.95L821.363 317.862Z" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <circle opacity="0.98" cx="875.689" cy="289.597" r="7.29694" transform="rotate(-66 875.689 289.597)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <path opacity="0.84" d="M941.859 332.31C942.727 332.852 942.682 334.131 941.779 334.611L916.818 347.883C915.915 348.363 914.83 347.686 914.866 346.663L915.852 318.41C915.888 317.388 917.017 316.787 917.885 317.329L941.859 332.31Z" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <circle opacity="0.8" cx="1058.95" cy="285.151" r="9.56976" transform="rotate(-82 1058.95 285.151)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <rect opacity="0.72" x="1214.29" y="298.612" width="14.3546" height="14.3546" rx="1.32913" transform="rotate(14 1214.29 298.612)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <circle opacity="0.77" cx="1313.15" cy="317.785" r="9.80901" transform="rotate(-71 1313.15 317.785)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <rect opacity="0.7" x="1407.01" y="314.562" width="14.5939" height="14.5939" rx="1.32913" transform="rotate(-128 1407.01 314.562)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <rect opacity="0.71" x="1531.95" y="283.992" width="15.7901" height="15.7901" rx="1.32913" transform="rotate(25 1531.95 283.992)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <circle opacity="0.93" cx="1575.25" cy="300.174" r="10.5267" transform="rotate(80 1575.25 300.174)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <rect opacity="0.72" x="1726" y="302.599" width="28.7093" height="28.7093" rx="1.32913" transform="rotate(39 1726 302.599)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <path opacity="0.83" d="M1828.33 303.794C1829.28 303.394 1830.3 304.164 1830.17 305.179L1827.37 328.029C1827.24 329.044 1826.06 329.544 1825.25 328.928L1806.86 315.074C1806.04 314.458 1806.2 313.189 1807.14 312.789L1828.33 303.794Z" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <circle opacity="0.71" cx="53.3552" cy="344.746" r="10.6464" transform="rotate(-4 53.3552 344.746)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <circle opacity="0.88" cx="245.814" cy="354.699" r="13.0388" transform="rotate(-98 245.814 354.699)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <circle opacity="0.78" cx="236.132" cy="367.838" r="7.17732" transform="rotate(96 236.132 367.838)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <path opacity="0.7" d="M410.729 354.987C411.746 355.094 412.266 356.262 411.665 357.09L400.569 372.362C399.968 373.19 398.696 373.057 398.28 372.122L390.601 354.876C390.185 353.942 390.937 352.907 391.955 353.014L410.729 354.987Z" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <circle opacity="0.96" cx="508.567" cy="324.416" r="12.2014" transform="rotate(-67 508.567 324.416)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <path opacity="0.92" d="M540.312 342.342C539.816 343.237 538.537 343.259 538.01 342.382L530.991 330.7C530.464 329.823 531.084 328.705 532.107 328.687L545.734 328.449C546.757 328.431 547.416 329.527 546.92 330.422L540.312 342.342Z" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <circle opacity="0.75" cx="1789.96" cy="812.45" r="12.3211" transform="rotate(110 1789.96 812.45)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

As you can see, I tried applying a linear gradient mask to "fade out" the image at the bottom, but it's not working. How do I have it fade out at the last 20% of the image? (opacity = 1 for first 80%, opacity fades out to 0 over the last 20%)?

Basically it doesn't appear I can fade out the image like this using CSS, I need to fade out the image by adding some sort of SVG linear gradient, but not sure how.

I tried this as well, but not getting any feedback:

```
<defs>
  <clipPath id="clip0_529_2072">
    <rect width="1848" height="862" fill="white" />
  </clipPath>
  <linearGradient id="fadeGrad" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%">
    <stop offset="0.5" stop-color="white" stop-opacity="1" />
    <stop offset="1" stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0" />
  </linearGradient>
  <mask id="fade" maskContentUnits="objectBoundingBox">
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#fadeGrad)" />
  </mask>
</defs>
```

Comment: You don't need the clipPath. Make the linear gradient from white to black. No need of stop-opacity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gradient should paint in black and white and the mask makes the white visible and the black not visible.

#### Update

The [gradientTransform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/gradientTransform) attribute can be used for rotating the gradient. The viewBox has a height of 862, but the rectangles and circles are all placed in the upper part (except for one circle), so I limit the gradient to the upper part by setting the height of the mask to 300 (ideally the height of the SVG/viewBox should match the content, so also around 300-400).

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 1848 862" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="fadeGrad" gradientTransform="rotate(90)">
      <stop offset="0.5" stop-color="white" />
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="black" />
    </linearGradient>
    <mask id="fade">
      <!--<rect width="1848" height="862" fill="url(#fadeGrad)" />-->
      <rect width="1848" height="300" fill="url(#fadeGrad)" />
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <g mask="url(#fade)">
    <g>
      <rect x="407.504" y="361.524" width="23.9244" height="23.9244" rx="1.32913" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <path d="M487.43 363.518C487.942 362.632 489.221 362.632 489.732 363.518L501.243 383.455C501.754 384.341 501.115 385.449 500.092 385.449H477.07C476.047 385.449 475.408 384.341 475.919 383.455L487.43 363.518Z" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <rect opacity="0.72" x="112.436" y="25.2535" width="28.47" height="28.47" rx="1.32913" transform="rotate(-14 112.436 25.2535)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <path opacity="0.92" d="M199.829 48.6394C200.848 48.7285 201.389 49.8877 200.802 50.7258L186.33 71.3941C185.743 72.2322 184.469 72.1207 184.036 71.1934L173.373 48.3261C172.941 47.3988 173.674 46.3511 174.694 46.4403L199.829 48.6394Z" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <circle opacity="0.89" cx="331.549" cy="32.5986" r="10.0483" transform="rotate(18 331.549 32.5986)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <rect opacity="0.72" x="384.909" y="43.8614" width="15.7901" height="15.7901" rx="1.32913" transform="rotate(47 384.909 43.8614)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <path opacity="0.99" d="M502.651 46.1519C503.672 46.2233 504.232 47.3728 503.66 48.2211L493.568 63.1841C492.995 64.0324 491.72 63.9431 491.271 63.0235L483.359 46.8015C482.91 45.8819 483.626 44.8216 484.646 44.8929L502.651 46.1519Z" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <circle opacity="0.86" cx="641.604" cy="27.6894" r="11.4837" transform="rotate(-11 641.604 27.6894)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <path opacity="0.93" d="M707.963 26.7505C708.228 25.7622 709.463 25.4312 710.187 26.1546L722.949 38.917C723.673 39.6405 723.342 40.8759 722.353 41.1407L704.92 45.812C703.931 46.0768 703.027 45.1725 703.292 44.1842L707.963 26.7505Z" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <rect opacity="0.94" x="741.117" y="6.64569" width="21.0535" height="21.0535" rx="1.32913" transform="rotate(-122 741.117 6.64569)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <path opacity="0.9" d="M883.534 49.3855C884.557 49.3677 885.216 50.4639 884.72 51.3588L876.371 66.4197C875.875 67.3146 874.597 67.3369 874.07 66.4599L865.201 51.6995C864.674 50.8225 865.294 49.7039 866.317 49.686L883.534 49.3855Z" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <circle opacity="0.93" cx="1007.81" cy="17.8048" r="13.8762" transform="rotate(-76 1007.81 17.8048)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <rect opacity="0.98" x="1042.83" y="27.9118" width="23.9244" height="23.9244" rx="1.32913" transform="rotate(162 1042.83 27.9118)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <circle cx="1185.31" cy="17.5446" r="14.3546" transform="rotate(-180 1185.31 17.5446)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <circle opacity="0.87" cx="1254.92" cy="12.65" r="9.56976" transform="rotate(-65 1254.92 12.65)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <circle opacity="0.71" cx="1392.7" cy="41.544" r="9.68939" transform="rotate(-38 1392.7 41.544)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <path opacity="0.88" d="M1467.05 47.0341C1468.06 46.8389 1468.9 47.8041 1468.56 48.7715L1461.07 70.5386C1460.74 71.506 1459.48 71.75 1458.81 70.9778L1443.71 53.6035C1443.03 52.8313 1443.45 51.622 1444.45 51.4267L1467.05 47.0341Z" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <path opacity="0.89" d="M1548.09 -5.22846C1547.07 -5.35316 1546.57 -6.53045 1547.19 -7.34758L1564.2 -29.9251C1564.82 -30.7422 1566.09 -30.5864 1566.49 -29.6445L1577.53 -3.62176C1577.93 -2.67993 1577.16 -1.65851 1576.15 -1.7832L1548.09 -5.22846Z" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <rect opacity="0.71" x="1724.68" y="6.64569" width="26.7953" height="26.7953" rx="1.32913" transform="rotate(-45 1724.68 6.64569)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <path opacity="0.7" d="M1768.7 30.1902C1769.61 29.7257 1770.69 30.4222 1770.63 31.444L1769.34 56.089C1769.29 57.1108 1768.15 57.6914 1767.29 57.1341L1746.59 43.6931C1745.73 43.1358 1745.8 41.8586 1746.71 41.3941L1768.7 30.1902Z" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <path opacity="0.95" d="M48.2634 74.7334C47.4252 75.3203 46.2661 74.7798 46.1769 73.7605L44.652 56.3309C44.5629 55.3116 45.6105 54.5781 46.5378 55.0105L62.3947 62.4047C63.322 62.8371 63.4335 64.1112 62.5954 64.698L48.2634 74.7334Z" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <rect opacity="0.7" x="172.247" y="58.8511" width="21.532" height="21.532" rx="1.32913" transform="rotate(-51 172.247 58.8511)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <circle opacity="0.7" cx="294.255" cy="70.8699" r="9.92863" transform="rotate(-67 294.255 70.8699)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <rect opacity="0.81" x="400.858" y="78.7881" width="14.3546" height="14.3546" rx="1.32913" transform="rotate(-26 400.858 78.7881)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <path opacity="0.72" d="M534.287 78.4336C534.022 77.4453 534.927 76.541 535.915 76.8058L550.147 80.6191C551.135 80.884 551.466 82.1193 550.743 82.8428L540.324 93.2611C539.601 93.9846 538.365 93.6535 538.101 92.6652L534.287 78.4336Z" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <path opacity="0.93" d="M592.734 47.7218C591.721 47.8642 590.933 46.8564 591.317 45.9077L598.492 28.1487C598.875 27.2001 600.142 27.0221 600.772 27.8283L612.564 42.9217C613.194 43.7279 612.715 44.9138 611.701 45.0562L592.734 47.7218Z" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <rect opacity="0.8" x="649.406" y="49.5471" width="22.0105" height="22.0105" rx="1.32913" transform="rotate(-83 649.406 49.5471)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <path opacity="0.79" d="M782.91 71.9042C783.21 70.9257 784.456 70.638 785.153 71.3863L794.825 81.7577C795.523 82.506 795.149 83.7291 794.152 83.9593L780.334 87.1493C779.337 87.3795 778.465 86.4441 778.764 85.4657L782.91 71.9042Z" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <path opacity="0.87" d="M875.592 71.8921C875.327 72.8804 874.092 73.2114 873.369 72.4879L860.997 60.1162C860.273 59.3927 860.604 58.1574 861.593 57.8925L878.493 53.3642C879.481 53.0994 880.385 54.0038 880.121 54.9921L875.592 71.8921Z" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <rect opacity="0.88" x="998.969" y="65.4968" width="21.0535" height="21.0535" rx="1.32913" transform="rotate(87 998.969 65.4968)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <path opacity="0.94" d="M1140.67 47.3072C1141.1 46.3799 1142.38 46.2684 1142.97 47.1065L1159.34 70.4903C1159.93 71.3285 1159.38 72.4876 1158.37 72.5768L1129.93 75.0648C1128.91 75.1539 1128.18 74.1063 1128.61 73.179L1140.67 47.3072Z" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <circle opacity="0.92" cx="1208.02" cy="71.1757" r="12.9192" transform="rotate(-138 1208.02 71.1757)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <rect opacity="0.78" x="1315.3" y="85.4338" width="24.8814" height="24.8814" rx="1.32913" transform="rotate(81 1315.3 85.4338)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <path opacity="0.9" d="M1430.16 55.2327C1429.17 54.9679 1428.84 53.7325 1429.56 53.009L1446.81 35.7538C1447.54 35.0303 1448.77 35.3613 1449.04 36.3496L1455.35 59.9207C1455.62 60.909 1454.71 61.8133 1453.73 61.5485L1430.16 55.2327Z" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <circle opacity="0.72" cx="1519.59" cy="77.6056" r="8.37354" transform="rotate(100 1519.59 77.6056)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <rect opacity="0.86" x="1595.75" y="54.8637" width="20.575" height="20.575" rx="1.32913" transform="rotate(164 1595.75 54.8637)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <path opacity="0.72" d="M1646.46 56.4546C1646.15 57.4277 1644.89 57.6936 1644.21 56.9332L1626.22 36.9509C1625.53 36.1906 1625.93 34.9742 1626.93 34.7615L1653.23 29.171C1654.23 28.9582 1655.09 29.9087 1654.77 30.8818L1646.46 56.4546Z" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <path opacity="0.87" d="M1756.22 59.9023C1755.85 60.8575 1754.59 61.0576 1753.94 60.2624L1743.8 47.7388C1743.16 46.9436 1743.62 45.7496 1744.63 45.5896L1760.54 43.0686C1761.55 42.9086 1762.36 43.9025 1761.99 44.8577L1756.22 59.9023Z" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <circle opacity="0.72" cx="96.8289" cy="116.07" r="12.3211" transform="rotate(93 96.8289 116.07)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <circle opacity="0.83" cx="194.679" cy="84.4305" r="9.80901" transform="rotate(-119 194.679 84.4305)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <path opacity="0.92" d="M284.317 124.301C283.984 125.269 282.729 125.513 282.058 124.741L272.392 113.621C271.72 112.849 272.137 111.64 273.141 111.444L287.604 108.633C288.608 108.438 289.447 109.403 289.114 110.371L284.317 124.301Z" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <rect opacity="0.81" x="364.972" y="116.373" width="24.1637" height="24.1637" rx="1.32913" transform="rotate(101 364.972 116.373)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <rect opacity="0.99" x="444.72" y="103.082" width="26.7953" height="26.7953" rx="1.32913" transform="rotate(19 444.72 103.082)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <circle opacity="0.9" cx="634.485" cy="132.988" r="10.6464" transform="rotate(-27 634.485 132.988)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <circle opacity="0.9" cx="693.638" cy="127.327" r="7.77543" transform="rotate(50 693.638 127.327)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <rect opacity="0.9" x="774.345" y="108.398" width="23.6852" height="23.6852" rx="1.32913" transform="rotate(-163 774.345 108.398)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <circle opacity="0.99" cx="924.989" cy="126.554" r="8.85203" transform="rotate(90 924.989 126.554)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <rect opacity="0.93" x="1018.91" y="96.436" width="27.7523" height="27.7523" rx="1.32913" transform="rotate(-173 1018.91 96.436)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <circle opacity="0.99" cx="1047.67" cy="121.531" r="11.6033" transform="rotate(-146 1047.67 121.531)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <circle opacity="0.89" cx="1198.24" cy="111.947" r="14.235" transform="rotate(178 1198.24 111.947)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <circle opacity="0.87" cx="1290.39" cy="108.095" r="12.3211" transform="rotate(93 1290.39 108.095)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <path opacity="0.7" d="M1368.54 112.789C1367.85 112.029 1368.25 110.813 1369.25 110.6L1393.12 105.526C1394.12 105.314 1394.97 106.264 1394.66 107.237L1387.12 130.445C1386.8 131.419 1385.55 131.684 1384.87 130.924L1368.54 112.789Z" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <rect opacity="0.88" x="1441.57" y="99.0943" width="23.6852" height="23.6852" rx="1.32913" transform="rotate(112 1441.57 99.0943)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <rect opacity="0.99" x="1601.07" y="97.7652" width="20.3357" height="20.3357" rx="1.32913" transform="rotate(168 1601.07 97.7652)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <rect opacity="0.98" x="1644.93" y="115.044" width="20.0965" height="20.0965" rx="1.32913" transform="rotate(65 1644.93 115.044)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <path opacity="0.83" d="M1733.45 88.7933C1732.43 88.8825 1731.7 87.8348 1732.13 86.9075L1743.96 61.5364C1744.4 60.6091 1745.67 60.4977 1746.26 61.3358L1762.31 84.267C1762.9 85.1052 1762.36 86.2643 1761.34 86.3535L1733.45 88.7933Z" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <circle opacity="0.79" cx="89.2603" cy="153.483" r="9.92863" transform="rotate(172 89.2603 153.483)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <circle opacity="0.93" cx="210.555" cy="165.098" r="9.45014" transform="rotate(-166 210.555 165.098)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <path opacity="0.87" d="M291.409 135.948C290.435 135.632 290.17 134.381 290.93 133.696L312.144 114.595C312.904 113.91 314.121 114.306 314.333 115.306L320.269 143.229C320.481 144.23 319.531 145.086 318.558 144.769L291.409 135.948Z" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <rect opacity="0.91" x="387.567" y="167.249" width="25.3599" height="25.3599" rx="1.32913" transform="rotate(-176 387.567 167.249)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <path opacity="0.76" d="M518.978 149.258C519.138 150.268 518.144 151.073 517.189 150.706L496.986 142.951C496.031 142.585 495.831 141.321 496.626 140.677L513.443 127.059C514.238 126.415 515.432 126.873 515.593 127.884L518.978 149.258Z" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <rect opacity="0.77" x="584.279" y="171.237" width="27.9916" height="27.9916" rx="1.32913" transform="rotate(114 584.279 171.237)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <path d="M684.904 166.948C684.143 166.263 684.409 165.012 685.382 164.696L706.489 157.838C707.462 157.522 708.412 158.378 708.2 159.379L703.586 181.086C703.373 182.087 702.156 182.482 701.396 181.798L684.904 166.948Z" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <path opacity="0.99" d="M753.68 179.413C754.677 179.643 755.051 180.866 754.353 181.615L735.261 202.088C734.563 202.836 733.317 202.549 733.018 201.57L724.834 174.8C724.534 173.821 725.407 172.886 726.404 173.116L753.68 179.413Z" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <circle opacity="0.76" cx="884.87" cy="173.423" r="8.37354" transform="rotate(31 884.87 173.423)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <path opacity="0.9" d="M968.451 176.592C968.273 177.6 967.071 178.037 966.287 177.379L950.557 164.18C949.773 163.522 949.995 162.263 950.956 161.913L970.253 154.889C971.214 154.539 972.194 155.361 972.016 156.369L968.451 176.592Z" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <rect opacity="0.83" x="1099.98" y="181.87" width="16.5078" height="16.5078" rx="1.32913" transform="rotate(-137 1099.98 181.87)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <rect opacity="0.92" x="1227.58" y="179.212" width="21.0535" height="21.0535" rx="1.32913" transform="rotate(-74 1227.58 179.212)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <rect opacity="0.91" x="1292.71" y="161.933" width="14.5939" height="14.5939" rx="1.32913" transform="rotate(167 1292.71 161.933)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <path opacity="0.75" d="M1414.12 170.366C1414.79 169.594 1416.05 169.838 1416.38 170.805L1422.89 189.699C1423.22 190.667 1422.38 191.632 1421.38 191.437L1401.76 187.624C1400.76 187.429 1400.34 186.219 1401.01 185.447L1414.12 170.366Z" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <rect opacity="0.97" x="1484.1" y="160.604" width="28.47" height="28.47" rx="1.32913" transform="rotate(125 1484.1 160.604)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <circle opacity="0.71" cx="1573.97" cy="167.125" r="13.1584" transform="rotate(152 1573.97 167.125)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <rect opacity="0.75" x="1639.61" y="181.87" width="27.2738" height="27.2738" rx="1.32913" transform="rotate(144 1639.61 181.87)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <circle opacity="0.77" cx="1834.01" cy="180.473" r="8.49317" transform="rotate(37 1834.01 180.473)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <circle opacity="0.78" cx="51.0069" cy="233.076" r="7.29694" transform="rotate(24 51.0069 233.076)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <circle opacity="0.86" cx="128.593" cy="197.128" r="12.4407" transform="rotate(121 128.593 197.128)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <path opacity="0.91" d="M254.16 198.319C254.373 197.319 255.589 196.923 256.35 197.608L267.299 207.467C268.059 208.151 267.793 209.402 266.82 209.719L252.808 214.272C251.835 214.588 250.884 213.732 251.097 212.731L254.16 198.319Z" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <circle opacity="0.91" cx="438.537" cy="200.245" r="10.5267" transform="rotate(-94 438.537 200.245)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <rect opacity="0.98" x="452.695" y="219.455" width="19.1395" height="19.1395" rx="1.32913" transform="rotate(107 452.695 219.455)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <rect opacity="0.95" x="633.457" y="190.214" width="24.4029" height="24.4029" rx="1.32913" transform="rotate(-120 633.457 190.214)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <circle opacity="0.93" cx="670.395" cy="222.284" r="8.97165" transform="rotate(28 670.395 222.284)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <circle opacity="0.86" cx="784.916" cy="208.493" r="14.3546" transform="rotate(30 784.916 208.493)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <rect opacity="0.8" x="924.537" y="207.493" width="21.532" height="21.532" rx="1.32913" transform="rotate(119 924.537 207.493)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <path opacity="0.72" d="M925.872 205.784C925.215 206.568 923.955 206.346 923.605 205.384L916.298 185.309C915.948 184.347 916.771 183.368 917.778 183.545L938.817 187.255C939.825 187.433 940.262 188.634 939.605 189.418L925.872 205.784Z" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <rect opacity="0.75" x="1058.78" y="218.126" width="24.1637" height="24.1637" rx="1.32913" transform="rotate(-35 1058.78 218.126)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <circle cx="1153.61" cy="232.03" r="10.5267" transform="rotate(117 1153.61 232.03)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <circle opacity="0.74" cx="1304.88" cy="203.461" r="10.6464" transform="rotate(-35 1304.88 203.461)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <rect opacity="0.86" x="1345.87" y="212.809" width="18.9003" height="18.9003" rx="1.32913" transform="rotate(-51 1345.87 212.809)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <rect opacity="0.82" x="1438.91" y="220.784" width="19.1395" height="19.1395" rx="1.32913" transform="rotate(107 1438.91 220.784)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <circle opacity="0.86" cx="1551.56" cy="221.788" r="11.2445" transform="rotate(-71 1551.56 221.788)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <path opacity="0.72" d="M1689.75 194.459C1689.09 195.242 1687.83 195.02 1687.48 194.059L1682.35 179.954C1682 178.993 1682.82 178.013 1683.83 178.191L1698.61 180.797C1699.62 180.975 1700.06 182.177 1699.4 182.96L1689.75 194.459Z" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <rect opacity="0.9" x="1747.27" y="215.467" width="18.9003" height="18.9003" rx="1.32913" transform="rotate(-149 1747.27 215.467)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <circle opacity="0.91" cx="58.043" cy="281.693" r="9.09128" transform="rotate(100 58.043 281.693)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <rect opacity="0.77" x="236.046" y="234.444" width="28.7093" height="28.7093" rx="1.32913" transform="rotate(131 236.046 234.444)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <rect opacity="0.93" x="303.831" y="257.04" width="20.0965" height="20.0965" rx="1.32913" transform="rotate(168 303.831 257.04)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <rect opacity="0.95" x="391.554" y="243.748" width="16.9863" height="16.9863" rx="1.32913" transform="rotate(-75 391.554 243.748)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <rect opacity="0.7" x="515.164" y="266.344" width="23.9244" height="23.9244" rx="1.32913" transform="rotate(-158 515.164 266.344)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <rect opacity="0.86" x="634.786" y="275.648" width="17.2256" height="17.2256" rx="1.32913" transform="rotate(34 634.786 275.648)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <rect opacity="0.96" x="717.192" y="271.66" width="24.8814" height="24.8814" rx="1.32913" transform="rotate(-9 717.192 271.66)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <path opacity="0.84" d="M735.951 266.589C735.809 267.602 734.623 268.081 733.816 267.451L713.716 251.747C712.91 251.118 713.088 249.851 714.037 249.468L737.687 239.912C738.635 239.529 739.643 240.317 739.501 241.33L735.951 266.589Z" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <rect x="928.524" y="239.761" width="16.9863" height="16.9863" rx="1.32913" transform="rotate(127 928.524 239.761)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <rect opacity="0.98" x="985.677" y="263.685" width="26.0776" height="26.0776" rx="1.32913" transform="rotate(44 985.677 263.685)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <circle opacity="0.78" cx="1077.39" cy="250.272" r="11.3641" transform="rotate(-135 1077.39 250.272)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <circle opacity="0.73" cx="1179.14" cy="277.508" r="12.0818" transform="rotate(9 1179.14 277.508)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <circle opacity="0.94" cx="1250.78" cy="255.621" r="13.0388" transform="rotate(83 1250.78 255.621)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <path opacity="0.86" d="M1390.44 250.199C1391.25 249.569 1392.43 250.048 1392.58 251.062L1394.32 263.463C1394.46 264.477 1393.45 265.264 1392.51 264.881L1380.89 260.189C1379.95 259.806 1379.77 258.539 1380.57 257.91L1390.44 250.199Z" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <rect opacity="0.95" x="1472.14" y="253.052" width="17.9433" height="17.9433" rx="1.32913" transform="rotate(65 1472.14 253.052)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <path opacity="0.94" d="M1565.08 273.54C1565.31 274.537 1564.37 275.409 1563.39 275.11L1541.64 268.46C1540.66 268.161 1540.37 266.915 1541.12 266.217L1557.76 250.705C1558.51 250.007 1559.73 250.381 1559.96 251.378L1565.08 273.54Z" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <rect opacity="0.75" x="1662.21" y="259.698" width="24.6421" height="24.6421" rx="1.32913" transform="rotate(-179 1662.21 259.698)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <circle opacity="0.74" cx="1754.06" cy="276.977" r="13.9958" transform="rotate(135 1754.06 276.977)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <path opacity="0.97" d="M150.643 309.39C150.59 308.368 151.662 307.672 152.574 308.136L169.64 316.832C170.552 317.296 170.619 318.574 169.76 319.131L153.697 329.563C152.839 330.12 151.699 329.539 151.646 328.518L150.643 309.39Z" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <path opacity="0.76" d="M144.539 318.751C143.701 319.338 142.542 318.798 142.453 317.779L141.024 301.45C140.935 300.431 141.983 299.697 142.91 300.129L157.765 307.057C158.693 307.489 158.804 308.763 157.966 309.35L144.539 318.751Z" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <circle opacity="0.81" cx="323.937" cy="276.144" r="12.9192" transform="rotate(-165 323.937 276.144)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <rect opacity="0.9" x="414.15" y="294.625" width="24.8814" height="24.8814" rx="1.32913" transform="rotate(69 414.15 294.625)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <circle opacity="0.79" cx="470.94" cy="275.159" r="8.25392" transform="rotate(-85 470.94 275.159)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <path opacity="0.81" d="M616.551 292.558C616.605 291.536 617.744 290.956 618.602 291.513L637.214 303.6C638.073 304.157 638.006 305.434 637.094 305.899L617.32 315.974C616.409 316.439 615.336 315.742 615.39 314.72L616.551 292.558Z" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <rect opacity="0.99" x="731.813" y="315.891" width="16.5078" height="16.5078" rx="1.32913" transform="rotate(-50 731.813 315.891)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <path opacity="0.73" d="M821.363 317.862C821.763 316.92 823.032 316.764 823.648 317.581L833.513 330.672C834.128 331.489 833.629 332.666 832.613 332.791L816.344 334.789C815.329 334.913 814.559 333.892 814.959 332.95L821.363 317.862Z" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <circle opacity="0.98" cx="875.689" cy="289.597" r="7.29694" transform="rotate(-66 875.689 289.597)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <path opacity="0.84" d="M941.859 332.31C942.727 332.852 942.682 334.131 941.779 334.611L916.818 347.883C915.915 348.363 914.83 347.686 914.866 346.663L915.852 318.41C915.888 317.388 917.017 316.787 917.885 317.329L941.859 332.31Z" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <circle opacity="0.8" cx="1058.95" cy="285.151" r="9.56976" transform="rotate(-82 1058.95 285.151)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <rect opacity="0.72" x="1214.29" y="298.612" width="14.3546" height="14.3546" rx="1.32913" transform="rotate(14 1214.29 298.612)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <circle opacity="0.77" cx="1313.15" cy="317.785" r="9.80901" transform="rotate(-71 1313.15 317.785)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <rect opacity="0.7" x="1407.01" y="314.562" width="14.5939" height="14.5939" rx="1.32913" transform="rotate(-128 1407.01 314.562)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <rect opacity="0.71" x="1531.95" y="283.992" width="15.7901" height="15.7901" rx="1.32913" transform="rotate(25 1531.95 283.992)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <circle opacity="0.93" cx="1575.25" cy="300.174" r="10.5267" transform="rotate(80 1575.25 300.174)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <rect opacity="0.72" x="1726" y="302.599" width="28.7093" height="28.7093" rx="1.32913" transform="rotate(39 1726 302.599)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <path opacity="0.83" d="M1828.33 303.794C1829.28 303.394 1830.3 304.164 1830.17 305.179L1827.37 328.029C1827.24 329.044 1826.06 329.544 1825.25 328.928L1806.86 315.074C1806.04 314.458 1806.2 313.189 1807.14 312.789L1828.33 303.794Z" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <circle opacity="0.71" cx="53.3552" cy="344.746" r="10.6464" transform="rotate(-4 53.3552 344.746)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <circle opacity="0.88" cx="245.814" cy="354.699" r="13.0388" transform="rotate(-98 245.814 354.699)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <circle opacity="0.78" cx="236.132" cy="367.838" r="7.17732" transform="rotate(96 236.132 367.838)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <path opacity="0.7" d="M410.729 354.987C411.746 355.094 412.266 356.262 411.665 357.09L400.569 372.362C399.968 373.19 398.696 373.057 398.28 372.122L390.601 354.876C390.185 353.942 390.937 352.907 391.955 353.014L410.729 354.987Z" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <circle opacity="0.96" cx="508.567" cy="324.416" r="12.2014" transform="rotate(-67 508.567 324.416)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      <path opacity="0.92" d="M540.312 342.342C539.816 343.237 538.537 343.259 538.01 342.382L530.991 330.7C530.464 329.823 531.084 328.705 532.107 328.687L545.734 328.449C546.757 328.431 547.416 329.527 546.92 330.422L540.312 342.342Z" fill="#C4C4C4" />
      -<circle opacity="0.75" cx="1789.96" cy="812.45" r="12.3211" transform="rotate(110 1789.96 812.45)" fill="#C4C4C4" />
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: This fades from left to right, how about from top to bottom?